# Cool tricks and expressive snippets with ruby collections/enumerables

Tags: ruby, collections, code-snippets, enumerable

What are your favorite code snippets with ruby collections? Preferably they should be discovery for you, be expressive, readable and introduce some fun in your coding practice.

---

Pattern-matching in arrays (for local variables and parameters):

```
(a, b), c = [[:a, :b], :c]
[a,b,c]
=> [:a, :b, :c]

(a,), = [[:a]]
a
=> :a
```

Assigning from non-arrays to multiple variables:

```
abc, a, b =* "abc".match(/(a)(b)./)
=> ["abc", "a", "b"]

nil1, =* "abc".match(/xyz/)
=> []
```

Initialize array elements with the same expression:

```
5.times.map { 1 }    
=> [1,1,1,1]

Array.new(5) { 1 }
=> [1,1,1,1,1]
```

Initialize array with the same value:

```
[2]*5
=>[2,2,2,2,2]

Array.new 5, 2
=>[2,2,2,2,2]
```

Sum elements of an array:

```
[1,2,3].reduce(0, &:+)

=> 6
```

Find all indices that match condition:

```
a.each_with_index.find_all { |e, i| some_predicate(e) }.map(&:last)
```

Alternate CSS classes:

```
(1..4).zip(%w[cls1 cls2].cycle)

=> [[1, "cls1"], [2, "cls2"], [3, "cls1"], [4, "cls2"]]
```

Unzipping:

```
keys, values = {a: 1, b: 2}.to_a.transpose
keys
=> [:a, :b]
```

Exploring boolean member methods of a string:

```
"".methods.sort.grep(/\?/)
```

Exploring string-specific methods:

```
"".methods.sort - [].methods
```

Answer (score 2):

Lazy Fibonacci series with memoization, taken from [Neeraj Singh](http://Neeraj.Name/2008/05/10/how-hash-works-with-block-in-ruby.html):

```
fibs = { 0 => 0, 1 => 1 }.tap do |fibs|
  fibs.default_proc = ->(fibs, n) { fibs[n] = fibs[n-1] + fibs[n-2] }
end

fibs.take(10).map(&:last).each(&method(:puts))
```

An implementation of Counting Sort:

```
module Enumerable
  def counting_sort(k)
    reduce(Array.new(k+1, 0)) {|counting, n| counting.tap { counting[n] += 1 }}.
    map.with_index {|count, n| [n] * count }.flatten
  end
end
```

An implementation of `sum` aka prefix sum:

```
module Enumerable
  def scan(initial=nil, sym=nil, &block)
    args = if initial then [initial] else [] end
    unless block_given?
      args, sym, initial = [], initial, first unless sym
      block = ->(acc, el) { acc.send(sym, el) }
    end
    [initial || first].tap {|res| 
      reduce(*args) {|acc, el| 
        block.(acc, el).tap {|e|
          res << e
        }
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Here, I experimented with having `Hash#each` yield `KeyValuePair`s instead of two-element `Array`s. It's quite surprising, how much code *still* works, after doing such a brutal monkey-patch. Yay, duck typing!

```
class Hash
  KeyValuePair = Struct.new(:key, :value) do
    def to_ary
      return key, value
    end
  end

  old_each = instance_method(:each)
  define_method(:each) do |&blk|
    old_each.bind(self).() do |k, v|
      blk.(KeyValuePair.new(k, v))
    end
  end
end
```

Something I have been playing around with is making `Enumerable#===` perform recursive structural pattern matching. I have no idea if this is in any way useful. I don't even know if it actually works.

```
module Enumerable
  def ===(other)
    all? {|el| 
      next true if el.nil?
      begin
        other.any? {|other_el| el === other_el }
      rescue NoMethodError => e
        raise unless e.message =~ /any\?/
        el === other
      end
    }
  end
end
```

Another thing I toyed around with recently was re-implementing all methods in `Enumerable`, but using `reduce` instead of `each` as the basis. In this case, I *know* it doesn't actually work properly.

```
module Enumerable
  def all?
    return reduce(true) {|res, el| break false unless res; res && el } unless block_given?
    reduce(true) {|res, el| break false unless res; res && yield(el) }
  end

  def any?
    return reduce(false) {|res, el| break true if res || el } unless block_given?
    reduce(false) {|res, el| break true if res || yield(el) }
  end

  def collect
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res << yield(el) }
  end
  alias_method :map, :collect

  def count(item=undefined = Object.new)
    return reduce(0) {|res, el| res + 1 if el == item } unless undefined.equal?(item)
    unless block_given?
      return size if respond_to? :size
      return reduce(0) {|res, el| res + 1 }
    end
    reduce(0) {|res, el| res + 1 if yield el }
  end

  def detect(ifnone=nil)
    reduce(ifnone) {|res, el| if yield el then el end unless res }
  end
  alias_method :find, :detect

  def drop(n=1)
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res.tap { res << el unless n -= 1 >= 0 }}
  end

  def drop_while
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res.tap { res << el unless yield el }}
  end

  def each
    tap { reduce(nil) {|_, el| yield el }}
  end

  def each_with_index
    tap { reduce(-1) {|i, el| (i+1).tap {|i| yield el, i }}}
  end

  def find_all
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res.tap {|res| res << el if yield el }}
  end
  alias_method :select, :find_all

  def find_index(item=undefined = Object.new)
    return reduce(-1) {|res, el| break res + 1 if el == item } unless undefined.equals?(item)
    reduce(-1) {|res, el| break res + 1 if yield el }
  end

  def grep(pattern)
    return reduce([]) {|res, el| res.tap {|res| res << el if pattern === el }} unless block_given?
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res.tap {|res| res << yield(el) if pattern === el }}
  end

  def group_by
    reduce(Hash.new {|hsh, key| hsh[key] = [] }) {|res, el| res.tap { res[yield el] = el }}
  end

  def include?(obj)
    reduce(false) {|res, el| break true if res || el == obj }
  end

  def reject
    reduce([]) {|res, el| res.tap {|res| res << el unless yield el }}
  end
end
```

Comment: Jörg, your Fibonacci example does not work: 
fibs.take(7)
=> [[0, 0], [1, 1]]

Comment: @Alexey: You're right. That's what I get for making a cool two-liner into a cool one-liner and not testing it afterwards ;-) Will investigate when I get back home.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize multiple values from an array:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b, *c = a

assert_equal [b, c], [1, [2,3]]

d, = a
assert_equal d, a[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

My own are:

Initialize array elements with same expression:

```
5.times.map { some_expression }
```

Initialize array with same value:

```
[value]*5
```

Sum elements of an array:

```
[1,2,3].reduce(0, &:+)
```

Find all indices that match condition:

```
a.each_with_index.find_all { |e, i| some_predicate(e) }.map(&:last)
```

Comment: I guess the reduce was just an example, because you have [1,2,3].sum. The last snippet could be written as "a.each_with_index.map { |e, i| i if some_predicate(e) }.compact", thought it may certainly generate a bigger intermediate array.

Comment: oops, it seems Enumerable#sum is in fact an extension, not vanilla Ruby.

Comment: Unless `value` is immutable, `[value] * 5` can give you a truckload of grief.

Comment: @Andrew, so use 5.times.map { some_expression } in mutable case or minimize mutation in your code

Answer (score 0):

Not really snippets, but I like these generic constructions (I show only how to use them, the implementation is easily found on the web).

Conversion Array -> Hash (`to_hash` or `mash`, the idea is the same, see *Facets* implementation):

```
>> [1, 2, 3].mash { |k| [k, 2*k] } 
=> {1=>2, 2=>4, 3=>6}
```

Map + select/detect: You want to do a map and get only the first result (so a `map { ... }.first` would inefficient):

```
>> [1, 2, 3].map_select { |k| 2*k if k > 1 } 
=> [4, 6]

>> [1, 2, 3].map_detect { |k| 2*k if k > 1 } 
=> 4
```

Lazy iterations (lazy_map, lazy_select, ...). Example:

```
>> 1.upto(1e100).lazy_map { |x| 2 *x }.first(5)
=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: Facets, Hashery and Tom's other libraries are a treasure trove of all sorts great Ruby code, not just related to collections and iterators.

Comment: def mash &body; Hash[map(&body)] end

Comment: BTW: that last one really bugs me. In Scala, for example, `map` & Co. are guaranteed to return the same collection type they are called on. In Ruby, they always return a concrete, strict, fully realized `Array`. In the case of a `Hash` or a `Tree`, that's just annoying, but in the case of a potenially infinite data structure like an `Enumerator`, that's just plain deadly. If `map` simply returned the same thing it was called on, you wouldn't need `lazy_map`, it would just work.

Comment: @Jörg, I definitely agree that Ruby's pervasive use of arrays was not a wise decision. Python kind of solved the problem with lazy generators, but I don't stil see how Ruby will do it in a nice way.

Comment: In most practical cases I like Ruby's approach more then Scala's. In Scala I had to translate result sequence to another type of sequence all the time, because almost always I need just array :)

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of items that meet either one condition or another:

```
items.count do |item|
  next true unless first_test?(item)
  next true unless second_test?(item)
  false
end
```

`count` means you don't have to do `i = 0` and `i += 1`.

`next` means that you can finish that iteration of the block and still supply the answer, rather than hanging around until the end.

(If you wanted, you could replace the last two lines of the block with the single line `! second_test?(item)`, but that'd make it look messier)

Comment: Why not to do it like this? items.count { |i| first_test?(i) or second_test?(i) }

Comment: @Alexey: You could, unless the real code is so verbose you couldn't easily fit it on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Exploring boolean member methods of a string:

```
"".methods.sort.grep(/\?/)
```

Exploring string-specific methods:

```
"".methods.sort - [].methods
```