# Flip array in chunks

Tags: ruby, arrays

I need to reverse an array in chunks of a specified size. Here is an example of what needs to happen:

```
chunk = 2
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

How can I build an array in which chunks are reversed like this:

```
[2, 1, 4, 3, 5]
```

My code:

```
arr.each_slice(chunk) { |a| p a }
```

outputs:

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
[5]
```

Each of the chunks above needs to be reversed and appended to a final array as seen above.

Comment: @sawa Why edit and then vote to close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr.each_slice(2).flat_map(&:reverse)
# => [2, 1, 4, 3, 5]
```

Comment: You could probably optimize with `flat_map(&:reverse)`

Comment: @tadman yes..done!! I forgot for a while that thing. thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Ah, cool.  I thought I had to use `reduce` but that seemed excessive.

Comment: @squiguy: Reduce is *universal*, you can do *everything* with it. You just don't always need to, if there is something more specialized available. (To "prove" its universality, I actually wrote a replacement for Ruby's `Enumerable` mixin once, where all methods were based on `reduce` instead of `each`. Some are a bit mind-bending but most are straightforward.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's interesting.  Might it be on Github? :)

Comment: @squiguy: Some sketches are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317439/cool-tricks-and-expressive-snippets-with-ruby-collections-enumerables/4317909#4317909 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833372/functional-code-examples-in-ruby/3834035#3834035 However, both of those are incomplete, and the stuff which *is* there is buggy. But it'll give you an idea. I never did anything more with that, since trying to *exactly* mimic the behavior of `Enumerable` is hard. Just look at the RubySpecs: https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/tree/master/core/enumerable